# Find existing relationship within nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm developing a test application which sells, allows ppl to read books online.

```
Match (books: Book)<-[:Likes]-(ppl:Reader)
```

I need cypher query to return list of Readers who likes books(I'm done with tis part)and relationship between them if any.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out answer by myself. But I'm not very sure it s correct way of doing it.

```
MATCH (book:Book),(group1:Reader),(group2:Reader)
MATCH (book)<-[:Likes]-(group1)

MATCH (book)<-[:Likes]-(group2)

MATCH (group1)-[r]-(group2)

RETURN group1.Name, type(r), group2.Name
```

Any suggestions or corrections are appropriated

Answer (score 2):

I assume here you only have two node Labels: `Book` and `Reader` and that `Reader` is a person. In this case you should probably call it a `Person` and the fact that they read a book or like a book is in the nature of relationships.

Your initial query was correct, but you didn't use the relationship.

It wasn't immediately clear to me from your question but I see that you are trying to find relationships between people. This should hopefully get you what you want.

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[:LIKES]->(book:Book)<-[:LIKES]-(p2:Person)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p1)-[r]->(p2)
RETURN p1, r, p2
```

Comment: Ur second query will return all the readers name in row form. But Im interested in listening relationship between readers ..

Comment: Updated - don't be so quick to downvote next time. It's not always clear what you are asking.